# Dynamically set variables exported from a JavaScript module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking for something like Python `globals()` or `locals()` in the context of the new JavaScript modules.

Here is the situation: there are two modules, `config.mjs` and `main.mjs`. The first one defines configuration for the program, the second uses that configuration. The goal is to allow to override the default configuration defined in `config.mjs` by passing a JSON configuration file as an argument. However, I don't know how to indirectly reference the variables the `config.mjs`  module exports?

`config.mjs`:

```
import fs from 'fs';

export let LOG_LEVEL = 1;

export function init()
{
    const config_file = fs.readFileSync("config.json");
    const config_struct = JSON.parse(config_file);
    for (const key in config_struct) {
        console.log(`  config_struct[${key}] = ${config_struct[key]}` );
        // how to automatically set the LOG_LEVEL variable from here?
    }
}
```

`config.json`:

```
{ "LOG_LEVEL" : 2 }
```

`main.mjs`:

```
import * as config from "./config";

config.init()
console.log(config.LOG_LEVEL);
```

The program currently prints `1`, but I would like it to print `2` — the value from the config file.

Comment: Why don't you export the `LOG_LEVEL` variable *after* you check if there is such value defined in `config.json`?

Comment: LOG_LEVEL = config_struct[key]

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek not sure it really changes the main question - how do I dynamically set the module's variables based on contents of an external file? Before you ask why do I need this, imagine that there are many configuration variables, and it's too cumbersome to have `if ... else ...` for each one (if defined in config file, use this value, else use default one).

Comment: @UthistranSelvaraj - there can be many keys in the configuration file. How do I export them all, without necessarily knowing all their names?

Comment: the key value should be unique right, you can use that value as defined in the answer

Comment: @kfx if you can have many many keys you can make use of spread operator. Does my answer below help? Or did I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are many keys possible in the `config.json` file then you can make use of spread operator:

**config.mjs**:

```
import fs from 'fs';

const configFile = fs.readFileSync("config.json");
const configStruct = JSON.parse(configFile); // assuming it exists, some check would be useful here

const defaultConfig = {
    LOG_LEVEL: 1,
    LOG_DIR: '/var/log/app.log',
    ...configStruct
};


export defaultConfig;
```

**config.json**:

```
{
    "LOG_LEVEL": 2
}
```

The spread operator in the first file will override only values that exist in `configStruct` (which is the content of `config.json`).

Does that work for you?

Comment: Hah, I felt the same when I discovered those cool array operators in Python with commas, colons, and negative indexes when I was working with matrices :D And now I miss them in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

The below changes should work I hope. not sure about the LOG_LEVEL variable declaration.

config.mjs:

```
import fs from 'fs';

export let LOG_LEVEL = 1;

export function init()
{
    const config_file = fs.readFileSync("config.json");
    const config_struct = JSON.parse(config_file);
    LOG_LEVEL = config_struct["LOG_LEVEL"];
}
```